# How to make multiple pins/annotations appear?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

this is my code below. On line 30 when I change the longitude and latitude to actual/hard coded numbers, I can see the pin on the map. But when I capture multiple longitude and latitude that's returned via decoding a json object, I  get the coordinates printed BUT it does not display it on the map. Any help would be great!

import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapKitViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    AuthorizationLogin.getStudentLocation(completion: handleStudentLocation(location:error:)
    )
}
func handleStudentLocation(location: [StudentLocationStruct], error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for locations in location {
            let latitude =  CLLocationDegrees(locations.latitude)
            let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(locations.longitude)
            self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude , longitude: longitude)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)
            
            print("Latitude \(latitude)")
            print("Longitude \(longitude)")
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please copy your code and paste it here. Images of code are hard to read and debug.

Comment: let annotation = MKPointAnnotation() ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're modifying the same `self.annotation` the whole time, only *one* point ever gets added, and then it gets modified on each iteration of the loop.

You should remove your `let annotation` property from your view controller and create a *new* one on each iteration of the loop:

```
func handleStudentLocation(location: [StudentLocationStruct], error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for locations in location {
            let latitude =  CLLocationDegrees(locations.latitude)
            let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(locations.longitude)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) 
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            
            print("Latitude \(latitude)")
            print("Longitude \(longitude)")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) Except shouldn't it be `MKPointAnnotation` rather than `MKMapAnnotation`?

Comment: The dangers of typing code in a browser window instead of running it through a compiler...

Comment: Yep. Normally I’m pretty good with that but we all make mistakes occasionally.

Comment: can you help me to do that? Like give me some tips as to how to create a new one each iteration

Comment: @EmHar that's what the code in my answer does

Comment: Thank you, good person. This was exactly the issue! For some reason I thought I had to find a way to dequeue each pin similarly to cells to make it work.

Comment: @EmHar great. You can accept the answer by clicking the green check mark.